# Prove that Lebesgue integral of a simple function written in non-canonical form is equal to the integral of the function written in canonical form.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I know that this question is going to get a lot of downvotes. But pardon me, because I have stuck here and have tried many things with no success. Now I state my problem.

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measured space and let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space. Let $h:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a simple function of the form:
$$h(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\mathcal{X}_{A_i}(\omega),$$
where $c_i>0$, $A_i\in\Sigma$ and $\mathcal{X}_{A_i}(\omega)$ denotes the indicator function. Here, I am assuming that the function $h(w)$ is written in a non-canonical form, meaning, for some $p,q\in\{1,2,...,n\} (p\neq q)$, we have that $A_p\cap A_q\neq \emptyset$. Now, it is a fact that a simple function can only take some finite non-negative values. So, let $t_1< t_2< t_3<...<t_m$ be the set of values which the function $h(w)$ takes. So, the function $h(w)$ can be written in its canonical form as follows
$$h(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} t_i \mathcal{X}_{\{\omega\in\Omega: h(\omega)=t_i\}}.$$
Note that in the above expression for $h(\omega)$, for $p,q\in\{1,2,3,...,m\}(p\neq q)$, we have that ${\{\omega\in\Omega: h(\omega)=t_p\}}\cap \{\omega\in\Omega: h(\omega)=t_q\}=\emptyset$ (since $h(w)$ is written in canonical form).

Now, I have to prove the following
$$\int\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\mathcal{X}_{A_i}(\omega)\big)d(\mu)=\int \big(\sum_{i=1}^{m} t_i \mathcal{X}_{\{\omega\in\Omega: h(\omega)=t_i\}}\big)d(\mu),$$
which means I have to prove the following
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\mu(A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}t_i\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega: h(\omega)=t_i\}).\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)$$

Here is what I have tried to prove the equation number $(1)$:

Let $t_r\in \{t_1,t_2,t_3,...,t_m\}$ be arbitrary such that $t_r\neq 0$.
Let $B=\{\omega\in\Omega: h(\omega)=t_r\}$. Define a collection of sets $\mathcal{F}$ as follows
$$\mathcal{F}=\{A_1\cap B, A_2\cap B, A_3\cap B,...,A_n\cap B\}.$$

I am able to prove that
$$B= (A_1\cap B)\cup(A_2\cap B)\cup(A_3\cap B)\cup...\cup (A_n\cap B).$$
But I am not able to figure out what to do next.

Can somebody help me mathematically derive the equation number $(1)$?

Comment: WLOG you can assume that all $c_i$ are distinct (if some are not throw them together). This hould lead to $n=m$ and $\forall i\exists j: c_i\mathcal{X}_{A_i}=t_j\mathcal{X}_{\{h=t_j\}}$ and this should let the problem evaporate.

Comment: @KurtG. ; No, it would not solve the problem because some of the $A_i$'s have non-empty intersections in my assumption.

Comment: Can you use linearity of the integral? If so, then you can just set the two representations equal and integrate both sides.

Comment: Ok. I was reading too quickly. One more step then: introduce some new $A_i$'s that are intersections of some old ones and associate to them the correct $c_i$. Then wlog they are all disjoint.

Comment: The original partition represented by the $A_i$ can surely be refined - there are only finitely many possible intersections ...

Comment: @Nirai ; I dont want to use linearity because am in the early phase of learning measure theory, and I know that this problem can be solved without invoking linearity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice and intuitive proof (without using the linearity of the integral) in Theorem 3.13 of Sheldon Axler's [Measure, Integration and Real Analysis](https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf). Just set $b_k = t_k$, and $B_k = h^{-1}(\{t_k\}) = \{\omega \in \Omega:h(\omega) = t_k\}$. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Robin Kurtz Did this help?